# How to set automation id for elements of xamarin.ios app for TestAutomation?

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I want setup test automation for xamarin ios app using Xamarin.UITest, there is a way to set Automation id for Xamarin.Forms project but not find way to setup for iOS app.

I have installed two nuget 
- Xamarin.UITest
- NUnit

and set up code in Test class file

```
var config = ConfigureApp
                .iOS
                .InstalledApp("package.identifier")
                .EnableLocalScreenshots();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "AccessibilityIdentifier" property for native iOS elements. I have tested and it is working at my end.

Comment: Never hurts to add a code example of the `AccessibilityIdentifier` object to help them understand how to use it.

Comment: That property can be found on the properties panel when selecting the element in storyboard file

Answer (score -1):

You can set up Automation ID's for each form element by going into MainPage.xaml and adding AutomationID = "idname" for each element in .
e.g.

```
   <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           AutomationId="Label1"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: But i'm looking for Xamarin.iOS [native] solution. @ssheode